# Django Connecting Image with Product Name from Admin

Tags: django, e-commerce, admin, project, commerce

Hey I hope someone will be able to help me out.

I'm working on a e-commerce website, I can add each product from the Admin db through django but I cant add the image, currently the code adds the same image to each product.

```
{% for Product in oldProducts %}
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <img class="img-circle" src="{% static "ecommerce/img/weightgain2.png" %}" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
      <h2>{{ Product.Name }}</h2>
      <p>{{ Product.Price }} </br> {{ Product.Description }}</p>
      <form method='POST' action="{% url 'ecommerce:addbasket' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="stuffNum" value="{{ Product.ProductID }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="stuffName" value="{{ Product.Name }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="stuffPri" value="{{ Product.Price }}">
      <input type="hidden" name="stuffDesc" value="{{ Product.Description }}">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Add To Basket</button>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    {% endfor %}
```

How can I make each product to take a different image with the same name as the product?

```
class Product(models.Model):
ProductID = models.AutoField(db_column='ProductId', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
Name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
Price = models.TextField(db_column='Price', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.
Description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
Image = models.TextField(db_column='Image', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Comment: Show your models please

Comment: thats the models for the product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `Textfield` instead of an `ImageField` which is why you can't choose an image to upload.

Better change to this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ProductID = models.AutoField(db_column='ProductId', primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    Price = models.TextField(db_column='Price', blank=True, null=True)
    Description = models.TextField(db_column='Description', blank=True, null=True)
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/dir/for/images/', db_column='Image', blank=True, null=True)
```

Then in your HTML write it like this:

```
{% for Product in oldProducts %}
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="img-circle" src={{ Product.Image.url }} alt="Generic placeholder image" width="140" height="140">
        ...
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**[PYTHON NOTES]**: Please use `product_id` instead of `ProductID` etc. Use snake case convention. This is Python, not JS ;)

Read more on the [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) or search Google for more.

Comment: Well it got me thinking now to work on this way. But 1: What happens when I upload the files into a server since the images are not stored in Database.

Comment: And 2: The 'Image' attribute has no file associated with it. this error comes up

Comment: Well, they are stored in the server. You don't want that? It's not a good practice to store image data in the database. The only thing that will be stored in the database will be the path.

Comment: You must upload a file first (!) in order to see it in the template.

Comment: I did, I uploaded the image through the Admin but this is coming up: Not Found: /ecommerce/alt="Generic
[23/Mar/2017 19:03:31] "GET /ecommerce/alt=%22Generic HTTP/1.1" 404 3818

Comment: I fixed it with my previous models, just had to change url style in the db. Thanks for your help